# emacs/aquamacs - send current line or selection to active terminal

Tags: emacs, remote-server, aquamacs, iterm2

I've been struggling to make a simple task working on my aquamacs.

I have an R session running on a remote server via ssh.

my Aquamacs is running locally on my machine.

What I want is to be able to send the current line or current selection to the active R session on my iterm2. This is easily done on sublime text 2 via the command "Cmd-Enter" with the plugin sendText.

How can we achieve that simple task ?

Best,

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just connecting to your R session from within emacs? It looks like SendText uses apple script to automate the behavior of other running applications, this could be done in Emacs but it's really not a good solution. The best solution would be to connect to your R session from within emacs, via a shell buffer or possibly a remote slime connection. Then use built in Emacs functions to send the process text.

Comment: Well for several reasons: 1) because I like working on iterm2 2) I tried to follow instructions for your suggestion following the post from "https://github.com/laco/emacs-starter-kit/blob/master/starter-kit-stats.org". Here the "M-x ess-remote" step failed with "No process is associated with this buffer" and I personnaly found this process complicated. Why not send "eval" to the active terminal as is the case with ST2 sendText?

Comment: The SendText source is very simple, the really important part is right here for you: https://github.com/wch/SendText/blob/master/SendText.py#L40-L43 you can easily port this to a call to `start-process` in Emacs, I may try it myself if I get time. In fact, I got started on it, but I'm not on a osx machine so I can't test it: https://gist.github.com/9981411

Comment: Thanks for your fast replies. This starts to look promissing. I inserted the "gist" code into my .emacs and tried to send the current line to my active iterm by `M-x sendtext:send-iterm2`. This gave the following error "The mark is not set now, so there is no region". As I do not know lisp and python, it was hard to me to debug. Did it work in your hand ?

Comment: For info, I found a solution by connecting to my R session from within emacs (first connecting to the remote server and there launching R) and using the `isend-mode`. Mainly, I followed the instructions on (https://github.com/ffevotte/isend-mode.el) and bound the send key with: `(eval-after-load "isend-mode"
'(define-key isend-mode-map (kbd "C-c RET") 'isend-send))`. Hope this will help others... Thanks JordonBiondo

Comment: Nice to hear you got it running! The code I pasted should send text that is in your region (highlighted) maybe that was the error.

Comment: @JordonBiondo, I am still curious about sending the text directly to iTerm. Did you manage to make the small plugin work, as you wanted to test it on osx? It is unresponsive when I try it myself, though no error is produced !!!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem, and found the following solution. I modified (very slightly) [this gist](https://gist.github.com/johnmastro/88cc318f4ce33b626c9d), and added it as a package to Aquamacs.

Here are the basic steps:

Copy the gist above into a new file, and then change the function `iterm-send-string` to the following:

```lisp
(defun iterm-send-string (str)   
  "Send STR to a running iTerm instance."
  (let* ((str (iterm-maybe-remove-empty-lines str))
         (str (iterm-handle-newline str))
         (str (iterm-escape-string str)))
    (shell-command (concat "osascript "
                          "-e 'tell app \"iTerm2\"' "
                          "-e 'tell current window' "
                          "-e 'tell current session' "
                          "-e 'write text \"" str "\"' "
                          "-e 'end tell' "
                          "-e 'end tell' "
                          "-e 'end tell' "))))
```

To make this a package you can add the following to the top of the file

```
;;; iterm.el --- sends selections to iTerm.app -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; modified from: https://gist.github.com/johnmastro/88cc318f4ce33b626c9d

;; Author: David Little <david.frank.little@gmail.com>
;; Keywords: lisp
;; Version: 0.0.1

;;; Commentary:

;; Works on Mac OS X: sends a selction to iTerm
;; To match SublimeText's key binding:
;; (global-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") 'iterm-send-text)

;;; Code:
```

Then you just need to call `M-x package-install-file`. Once you bind the `iterm-send-text` function to a shortcut (e.g. `C-return` in the comments above) you should be in business!